# A published fix for 11.04 Classic graphics mode only partly repairs my problem

Tags: 11.04, gnome, graphics, mode

The published fix (Fix Ubuntu / Linux Mint forgetting the theme) for the Classic graphics mode as outlined below only partially fixed my problem.

With the fix in place, Top Panel remains in high graphics mode for less than ten seconds. It then reverts to the dull "no effects" style.

However the files beneath the Places Menu remain in high graphics mode as do Files on the Desktop. Any assistance would be gratefully received. Thank you.

My graphics card is a Radeon hd5770 HDMI with proprietry driver installed

Open a terminal and paste this (I would have said to use ALT + F2 but in Unity, you can't paste inside the ALT + F2 dialog):

```
gksudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop
```

In the gnome-settings-daemon.desktop file, replace the following line:

```
Exec=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
```

With this:

```
Exec=bash -c "sleep 5; /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon"
```

[source](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/fix-ubuntu-linux-mint-theme-changing-to.html)

Comment: The Graphics Card is the Radeon hd5770 HDMI with proprietry driver installed. The commands in the link certainly do rectify part of the problem as described.

Comment: Sorry about the Link is this better? http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/fix-ubuntu-linux-mint-theme-changing-to.html I am very sorry about that - don't know how it happened.

Comment: Yes, replacing that line is the fix quoted, but it doesn't produce a complete result for me - Top Panel remains in low graphics mode after 6 or 7 seconds of being O.K.

Comment: I have moved on from 11.04 - Now have 11.10 installed which has one problem which I have posted here - Thank you.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure :)